# hide indent guide / ace editor

Tags: editor, ace-editor

I cannot find answers, could you kindly help me in the following matter?

I'd like to hide the indent guides for ace editor. The following does not work, everything else does:

editor.setDisplayIndentGuides(false);

The option above is not documented, see here:
https://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=editor

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use `editor.setOption` instead

```
editor.setOption("displayIndentGuides", false)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The indent guides simply reappears. I've triple checked it.

Comment: can you reproduce the issue on https://ace.c9.io/? when it reappears is editor.getOption("displayIndentGuides") still false?

Comment: yes, I can reproduce it here: https://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html - writing <<<<< chars at the top above the function shows errors in the margin, and checking or unchecking the Show Indent Guides does not help

Comment: indent guides are the lines showing indent levels, erros in the margin can be disabled with editor.session.setUseWorker(false)

Comment: That's what I was looking for, I mixed up the options. Thanks a lot. Consider this solved.